# OutOfMemoryError occurred in Oracle driver when setFetchSize in PreparedStatement

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement, ojdbc

I have this code, this code basically set limits in the `PreparedStatement` to avoid loading the whole table data.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql, ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        if (getDataSheet().isPagingEnabled()) {
            pstmt.setFetchSize(getDataSheet().getPageSize() + 1);
        }
        
        if (getDataSheet().isDisableTotalRowsCount() && maxRecords >= 0) {
            if (getDataSheet().isPagingEnabled()) {
                pstmt.setMaxRows(getCurrentPageSize());
            } else {
                pstmt.setMaxRows(maxRecords);
            }
        }
        
        //the rest of code.
        
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        //handle exception
    }
```

This code is just working fine for all DB vendors, except one case in Oracle driver if i used the `setFetchSize` in the `PreparedStatement`, and the page size was more than 20000 the driver throw an OutOfMemoryError

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.getCharBuffer(PhysicalConnection.java:7018)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.prepareAccessors(OracleStatement.java:907)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIdcb.receiveCommon(T4CTTIdcb.java:261)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIdcb.receive(T4CTTIdcb.java:127)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:992)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:194)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:791)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:866)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1186)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3387)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3431)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1203)
```

any idea why is that happening in Oracle ? Is there any thing to do in the DB level ?

Comment: Why would you want to fetch 20k rows in one go? The use of fetch size is to fetch a batch of rows, do something with it, then fetch another batch -- thus limiting the number of round-trips to the DB. It is **not** meant to fetch all rows in one massive in-memory batch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Contrary to what you seem to think, the `setFetchSize` does not limit the amount of records retrieved, it determines (or hints) how many records the driver should prefetch and cache. The exception is MySQL, which always prefetches all records, unless you set the fetch size to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

The driver is simply retrieving so much rows that memory gets exhausted.

Comment: Yea i see, i had a missunderstanding to `setFetchSize`, Ok then is it a best practice or the best number to `setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE)` ?

Comment: @JUBA No, you should use a reasonable number (say between 1 and 500); effect may vary per driver and database (and I'd advise to test if it actually improves performance). `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is a stupid hack for MySQL only!